# PHPExcel Error: Array and string offset access syntax with curly braces is deprecated

Tags: php, laravel, phpexcel

I've just updated my `phpexcel` to `phpspreadsheet`, and I noticed this error pops up:

> ErrorException (E_DEPRECATED)
> Array and string offset access syntax with curly braces is deprecated

> require 'Classes/PHPExcel.php';

here is part of my code which is triggering the above error:

**File:** `project/public/Classes/PHPExcel/Shared/ZipStreamWrapper.php`

```
  public function stream_open($path, $mode, $options, &$opened_path)
    {
        // Check for mode
        if ($mode{0} != 'r') { //Error Line
            throw new PHPExcel_Reader_Exception('Mode ' . $mode . ' is not supported. Only read mode is supported.');
        }
```

**File:** `project/public/Classes/PHPExcel.php`

```
/** PHPExcel root directory */
if (!defined('PHPEXCEL_ROOT')) {
    define('PHPEXCEL_ROOT', dirname(__FILE__) . '/');
    require(PHPEXCEL_ROOT . 'PHPExcel/Autoloader.php'); //Error Line
}
```

**File:** `app/Http/Controllers/analyticsAuth/statement.old.php`

```
use PHPExcel_Reader_Excel2007;
use PHPExcel; 
use PHPExcel_IOFactory;
use ZipArchive;
require 'Classes/PHPExcel.php'; //Error Line
```

**File:** `project/public/Classes/PHPExcel/Autoloader.php`

```
PHPExcel_Autoloader::Register();
PHPExcel_Shared_ZipStreamWrapper::register(); //Error Line
if (ini_get('mbstring.func_overload') & 2) {
    throw new Exception('Multibyte function overloading in PHP must be disabled for string functions (2).');
}
```

Thank you

Comment: You probably need your `require` to be before the other `use` statements. Are you sure `Classes/PHPExcel.php` exists? If you replace `require` with `include` and the error goes away, it means the file can't be found.

Comment: @HeySora, I haven't removed PHPExcel yet.

Comment: But I'm trying to Migrate from `phpexcel` to `phpspreadsheet`.

Comment: Thanks for adding the actual error to your question. An `E_DEPRECATED` error means some piece of code used to be valid in a previous PHP version, but isn't valid anymore. You should have details under the error in order to locate the file name as well as the line number.

Comment: @HeySora, I've added detailed of the following Error.

Comment: You need to go further in `PHPExcel_Shared_ZipStreamWrapper`.

Comment: Added that too. Please check and let me know if anything else is required.

Comment: The error is ` Array and string offset access syntax with curly braces is deprecated`. The code that throws the error is `$mode{0}`. It needs to be replaced with `$mode[0]`. Repeat this operation for any remaining error, and you'll be done.

Comment: If you are in laravel and not using  Maatwebsite/Laravel-Excel package you are doing something wrong imo

Comment: @HeySora, Thanks Got the answer.

Comment: This library already depreciated. You can use PHPOffice/PhpSpreadsheet instead

Answer (score 13, accepted):

This can be fix by replacing the curly braces `{}` with square brackets `[]`

I would like to give credit to the [@HeySora](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6401290/heysora) who made the comment and pointed out the exact issue in this particular case.

Comment: Where had you changed the bracket? Can you share the code?

Comment: Everyone should be advised that PHPExcel is a DEAD repository and project and the code is depricated and not being maintained in any way at all. Do not attempt to try and update it, it is a fool's errand. Easier Instead to consider using PhpSpreadsheet, which is a fine replacement. I was able to only change several lines of code where I just point to it instead of the PhpExcell in my code, and also I just replaced PhpExcell's wording with PhpSpreadsheets version of that, and viola! code worked fine. Also use PhpSpreadsheets instruction to install it. works fine using composer.

Answer (score 3):

This is not longer in use `$mode{0}` in php 7. it has been deprecated. Instead of using that use this `$mode[0]`